# Adding a view inside a custom view

Tags: android, view, custom-view

I am trying to add a progressbar(circular spinner) inside a RelativeLayout. The relativeLayout is visible, however the progressbar doesn't show up. Following is the code I am using but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public class MyCustomView extends RelativeLayout
{

    RelativeLayout rLayout;
    ProgressBar mProgressbar;

    public void init()
    {

        mProgressbar = new ProgressBar(mContext, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        mProgressbar.setLayoutParams(params);

        rLayout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        rLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

        rLayout.addView(mProgressbar);
        addView(rLayout);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

        if(rLayout != null)
        {
            rLayout.layout(l, t, r, b);
        }
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I am trying to add a progressbar(circular spinner) inside a RelativeLayout. The relativeLayout is visible, however the progressbar doesn't show up. Following is the code I am using but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public class MyCustomView extends RelativeLayout
{
    ProgressBar mProgressbar;

    public void init()
    {

        mProgressbar = new ProgressBar(mContext, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        mProgressbar.setLayoutParams(params);

        addView(mProgressbar);
    }

}
```

Progressbar doesn't even show up now?

**My Goals:**

- Showing ProgressBar in the center of the MyCustomView.

Comment: extend RelativeLayout, not ViewGroup

Comment: Just did that. It works but the progressbar isn't centered

Comment: this is most likely, because you used wrong LayoutParams

Comment: I don't see a mistake there. I have also added a rule to center_in_parent

Comment: do you have onLayout/onMeasure reimplemented?

Comment: for `MyCustomView`? I have implemented onLayout for MyCustomView but not the onMeasure.

Comment: so comment it out for a while and see what happens

Comment: If I comment onLayout() , even the RelativeLayout doesn't show up

Comment: what RelativeLayout? your MyCustomView is a RelativeLayout, why do you need another one?

Comment: If I comment onLayout() shown in the code above, rLayout doesn't show up. rLayout is the parent of ProgressBar and rLayout is a child of the CustomView.

Comment: again: what is RelativeLayout rLayout; for? your MyCustomView is a RelativeLayout, no need for another one

Comment: I used rLayout in a thinking that it would help me in centering the Progressbar. Then how can I center the Progressbar, if I add it to MyCustomView directly?

Comment: you don't have to do anything: when you use proper LayoutParams it will be done automatically

Comment: @pskink Please look at the updated code.

Comment: i run your code and it works correctly

Comment: It doesn't showup at all on my device.

Comment: run it on the emulator and see the view hierarchy using hierarchyviewer, what do you see?

Comment: and what does hierarchyviewer show?